# Photo Slider in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do image slider in my project. My requirement is to show all the thumbnails of the images from the database.And if click any image it should get enlarged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LightBox pluging of jQuery. Please take a look to the below links.

http://warren.mesozen.com/jquery-lightbox/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerylightbox_bal

http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-lightbox/demo/

Hope this helps